# Get remote JSON without Jquery?

Tags: javascript, json

What I want to do specifically is get the Vimeo thumbnail image by grabbing the json data returned by a request. I can't use jquery due to the javascript file being a small remote file that the user calls and jquery would increase its size many many times.

I have looked and everything seems to be talking about jquery or getting it in another language (php for instance).

I have found I need to do this so far:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = theUrlToMakeTheRequest;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

I am not sure what I need to make the callback and not sure what I need to do to be able to use the url that gets appended.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL JSONP is supported.

Comment: @qitch: What is the format of the data returned by the request? Are you sure this is JSON, not eg. JSONP? Give us the exact content of the resouce available at the URL stored in `theUrlToMakeTheRequest`.

Comment: @Tadeck here is an example: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/34041516.json

Comment: Just make a JSONP request then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From vimeo's documentation

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/simple-api

It looks like you can put a ?callback=myfunction parameter on the end of the url to do a jsonp type of callback.  So your code would maybe look something like this.

```
function myfunction(data) {
    alert(data);
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = theUrlToMakeTheRequest + '?callback=myfunction';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Their downloads page looks to have examples for just what you are trying to do.
http://vimeo.com/api/docs/downloads

Comment: (This is also known as JSONP.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a raw XMLHttpRequest,

Or for a small lightweight library that can do it check out zepto.js

If you just include zepto.js and ajax.js from...
https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/tree/master/src

You would have a JQuery compatible solution in 30k uncompressed javascript (probably < 4k minified)

Comment: I'm not sure the XMLHttpRequest solution will work in this case since it is on another domain.

Comment: Hmm, yep, depending on whether Vimeo send 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers then the cross domain call could be blocked. Looks like the JSONP rout is the best bet as per other answers.